# Is bias a property of the estimator, or of particular estimates?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, bias, estimators

As an example, I often encounter students who know that Observed $R^2$ is a biased estimator of Population $R^2$. Then, when writing up their reports, they say things like:

"I calculated Observed $R^2$ and Adjusted $R^2$, and they were pretty similar, suggesting only a small amount of bias in the Observed $R^2$ value we obtained."

I get that generally when we talk about bias we're typically talking about the properties of estimators rather than particular estimates. However, is the quoted statement above a misuse of terminology, or is it OK?

Comment: As usually defined in texts of mathematical statistics, bias ($=\text{E}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) $) is a property of the estimator, not of the particular estimate.  But, bias also has its meaning from colloquial use, and that is maybe what the students mean in the second instance.  I think what the students are saying in their argument is understandable, and interesting, showing that they actually thought by themselves, and are not only paroting some text!  So, you should take that as an opportunity, not simply mmarking as an "error", and ask "is this interesting argument actualy TRUE? that would

Comment: ....  make for a good question here!

Comment: I guess my concern was that there's a pretty long history in statistics of people mixing up technical terms (e.g. "confidence") with their non-technical counterparts. I agree that the line of argument I'm reading sounds quite reasonable, especially since the tendency to produce biased estimates is the defining property of biased estimators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In statistics, bias is clearly a property of the estimator.

I share your observation that bias is often incorrectly applied to estimates. Your example seems rather innocent in that regard, because a well-meaning instructor could argue that your students assumed that the error of the estimates is so small that it's OK to equate the estimate with the estimator.

A more extreme example would be the use of the word "bias" for the error of a particular estimate, as in: we know the true value is 5, but our estimate was biased upwards. I feel this is indeed a misuse of terminology that will eventually lead to confusion, and one should therefore flag it as inappropriate.

Comment: If not bias, then what would you call it when we (somehow) know that the estimated number is wrong?

Comment: Error https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator#Error

Comment: @Repmat "Know that ... is wrong" usually isn't a fruitful way to assess an estimator. In many circumstances even the best estimator is *certainly* wrong all the time. This occurs even in the simplest, most natural situations. Suppose (as in Buffon's Needle Problem), that a coin truly has a chance $p=2/\pi$ of landing heads and you use any estimator of $p$ that has ever been proposed, such as the proportion of heads observed in $n$ tosses.  Because that proportion is rational but $p$ is irrational, the value returned by that estimator will *never* be correct, no matter how many tosses are made!

Answer (score 6):

Bias is the property of an estimator.

An *estimator* is itself a random variable and has a distribution (with a mean and variance). When an estimator has an expected value that is equal to the true, unknown value that it's trying to estimate we say the estimator is unbiased.

Now, when we calculate an *estimate* we are looking at one observation from the distribution of the estimator. So, even if we go with the (incorrect yet innocuous in this context) definition of bias the student seems to be using, there's a problem. The single observation (the estimate), may be very far from the expected value of the estimator's distribution. In other words, it's possible the value of the estimate is very far from the true underlying value where the student seems to be implying that the Observed $R^2$ is very close to it's true value.

Comment: Well, yes, but the interesting, implied question, seems to be: If, on the same model & data, one unbiased and another biased estimator, are very close, does that make it possible to make some conclusion? which?